# “Where is that club with which Mr. Melville was laying about him so?” what's "was laying with that club about him so"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “Where is that club with which Mr. Melville was laying about him so?”

what does this mean? I think it is typo, so it should be 'lying'.

Comment: Please always provide the name of the book, the author and the year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. *Lay about (oneself)* is a rather old-fashioned phrasal verb meaning [To strike blows in all directions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lay_about).

*So*, on the end of a clause like this, means "so much", or "so extremely". Here, it would mean "so violently".